# iis 7 SSL website does not display in internet explorer 8 and 9 on 32 bit client machines

Tags: iis, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, 64-bit, 32-bit

However, in 64 bit machines ie8 and ie9 display the website fine.  Chrome, firefox, safari display the website fine in 32 or 64 bit client machines.

I have no idea where to start here...I'm assuming this is an IIS issue and can be solved by altering the configuration of the site.  Does anyone have any clue as to where to start?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking IE settings, as I am not sure you can play around with IIS or SSL to set it for particular browsers.